# Bootstrap Link color

Tags: html, css

hi guys i need some help with bootstrap 3.3.7.

how to change the color of an  element in bootstrap?
i tried various things i found on the internet, but none of them worked.
one thing i tried was this:

```
    a: hover{

        color:#some color;


         }

a:active{

        color:#some color;


         }

a:visited{

        color:#some color;


         }
```

on google i could not find what i searched.
i hope you guys can provide me with an answer,

thanks in advance

Comment: you can change it in bootstrap's css file manually

Comment: NEED MORE INFO.  So, i first suspect your include order is off, and its getting overridden. Make sure your styles that you have above, are getting loaded After the bootstrap defaults. Or, if you have only one css file, put those on the bottom.  Now there's the other issue, scope issue, try something like this body `{   a: hover{
        color:#some color;

         }
}` 
The reason why this is an issue im not sure, but you need to use the same tag structure as your other styles, so to properly override, you have to be careful how/when you nest.
Ill add an answer if this works.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the order of your link file, Twitter Bootstrap might be overriding it if you have that link after your styles.css.

For instance, if your index.html looks like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet", href="mystyles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet", href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

All the css you wrote might be being overwritten by Twitter-Bootstrap.
So to fix it, make sure you have your custom style.css after the twitter-bootstrap link.

If that doesn't solve it, you can simply put a `!important` after your custom css like this:

```
a: hover {
   color: blue !important;
}
```

This should solve your issue.